Absolute convergence of a series of functions
I came across the definition of absolute convergence of a series of functions and I am unsure if I did understand said definition correctly.
Thus far, the only notion of absolute convergence I knew was the following.
Absolute convergence of a series of numbers:
Let $\sum a_n$ be a sequence of (real) numbers. We say that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely if $\sum|a_n|$ converges.
For convergence of sequences of functions I know the pointwise and uniform convergence.
Uniform convergence of a series of functions:
Let $\sum f_n$ be a sereis of functions. Let $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k$ be the partial sum. We say that the series converges uniformly if the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly.
I am trying to understand the following definition:
Absolute convergence of a series of functions:
A series $\sum f_n$ is said to converge absolutely if for every $x \in D$ the series $\sum|f_n(z)|$ converges.
My thoughts:
Let $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$, i.e $(s_n)$ is a sequence of functions.
Especially for some $n$, $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ is a function. For this function $s_n$ we can consider the pointwise convergence, i.e. let $x$ be in the domain $D$ of $s_n$, then we consider $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^nf_k)(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$. Now this far, this was the usual pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions.
If we demand the pointwise convergence of this sereis of (real) numbers $\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$ to be absolute, we need that
$\sum_{k=1}^n|f_k(x)|$ converges.
Conclusion:
So for a series of functions $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ to be absolute convergent, means that for every point $x$ in the domain $D$ of $(s_n)$, the pointwise limit, that in this case is the limit of a series, has to converge absolutely.

Yes, you understand it correctly. The absolute convergence of a series of functions $\sum f_{k}$ in a domain $D$ is merely the absolute convergence of the series (plural) of numbers $\sum f_{k}(x)$ for each $x\in D$.

Presumably, in your definition, you either mean $z\in D,$ of you mean $\sum|f_n(x)|.$
